# Port-forwarding B310s-518 device through T-Mobile Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, ipv6

I am attempting to port-forward a device connected to a Huawei B310s-518 LTE modem on the T-Mobile network. From looking around it seems that I can't connect through IPv4 due to T-Mobile enabling Carrier Grade NAT but is this true for IPv6?

I cannot forward any ports at all after trying even non-standard ports (above 30000).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

None of the ports can be forwarded in IPV4 carrier grade NAT, it's because you do not have control over the router that's actually doing the NAT.

IPV6 doesn't really need NAT because it was traditionally used for the exhausted IPV4 address problem. (32bit addresses vs 128bit). My limited understanding of what T-Mobile has done seems to be a pure IPV6 network with "IPV4 tunneling". So, if that's the case, I don't see why you couldn't access a service hosted on a IPV6 device, as long as you are connecting with a IPV6 device.

This really depends on T-Mobiles network configuration, and how they have setup their Network for incoming requests.

If you try it and it doesn't work, you can always call them and see if they offer global IPV4 addressing by request. (It's a long shot)

Also check out this answer over at security-stackexchange:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44065/with-ipv6-do-we-need-to-use-nat-any-more

This one may also help: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/184524/switching-to-ipv6-implies-dropping-nat-is-that-a-good-thing